# Commit And Rollback in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, commit, rollback

This is my C# WinForm Code I have 2 stored procedure, the 1st doing Insert in `Table1` and the 2nd doing Update in `Table2` both are in a for loop. Please guide me on how to use Commit and Rollback in this code because I have GridView and GridView have many rows if any row have incorrect data then no rows get inserted and updated in Tables

```
try
{
    con.Open();

    da = DateTime.Now;
    if (txt_challanno.Text == "")
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Insert Order No.", "Message Box Sample", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
        toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Warning!";
        toolTip1.Show("Missing 'Lot No.'", txt_challanno);
    }
    else if (txt_challanno.Text != "" && DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["program_no"].Value == null)
    {
        toolTip1.Hide(txt_challanno);
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Program No.");
    }
    else if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["program_no"].Value != null && dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["bundle_weight"].Value == null)
    {
        toolTip1.Hide(txt_challanno);
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Bundle Weight");
    }
    else if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["bundle_weight"].Value == null && dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["pcs"].Value == null)
    {
        toolTip1.Hide(txt_challanno);
        MessageBox.Show("Insert Pcs");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Double r_weight1 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["r_weight"].Value);
            Double use_weight1 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["use_weight"].Value);
            Double r_rolls = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["r_rolls"].Value);
            Double use_rolls = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["use_rolls"].Value);


            if (use_weight <= r_weight1 && use_rolls <= r_rolls)
            {

                string a = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["pcs_wt"].Value.ToString();
                var data = Regex.Match(a, @"\d+").Value;
                var6 = Convert.ToDouble(data);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dailycuttinginsert", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@challan_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_challanno.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@size_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["size"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@quality_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["quality"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@use_weight", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["use_weight"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@use_rolls", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["use_rolls"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@bundle_weight", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["bundle_weight"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ls", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ls"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@shape", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["shape"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["b"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@total_pcs", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["total_pcs"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@avg", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["avg"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pcs_wt", SqlDbType.Float).Value = var6;/*Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["pcs_wt"].Value)*/
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cutting_size", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cutting"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dt"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = da.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@r_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id1"].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@balance_pcs", SqlDbType.Float).Value = 0;
                db.insertprocedure(cmd);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();


                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("dailycuttinginsert", con);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@challan_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_challanno.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@r_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id1"].Value.ToString();
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@balance_weight", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["bal_weight"].Value);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@balance_rolls", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["bal_rolls"].Value);
                db.insertprocedure(cmd1);
                cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            else { }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
        frmload();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally { con.Close(); }
```

Comment: This should probably be on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what about to use TransactionScope  http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First thing you want is to start the transaction immediately after you open the connection. Also, please move the connection opening out of the `try` block and wrap its creation in the `using` - this is a good practice for `IDisposable` implementations:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // your code before conn.Open()
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
    
    try
    {
    // your code goes here
```

Then leave everything as it is, and then in the end of the operation commit the transaction:

```
tran.Commit();
MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
frmload();
```

Also note that there is no `finally` because `using` is taking care of closing the connection in case of exceptions.

Comment: How are you calling it? Note that the code in the post does not use `SqlCommand` object at all - only `con`

Comment: thx bro its working confusing in defining tran in sqlCommand because i search commit roll there have many posts have define tran in sqlcommand without defining its work thx

Comment: @Andrei In store procedure i have setup to do commit and Rollback. Should i still write Commit and Rollback logic in C# when i call that SPROC ?

Comment: @Mvcdev, depends on how you organize your rollbacks. If you do error catching inside the stored proc and then rollback (as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531352/how-to-rollback-a-transaction-in-a-stored-procedure)), then you should be fine

Comment: why we need tran.Rollback? when connection closed, it will automatically rolls back any open transaction

Comment: FLICKER is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389131/109941