# Rollback with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex script with many stored procedures that I like to rollback.

I ask if in a situation like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(1);  
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(2);  

EXEC MyStoredProcedure

ROLLBACK;
```

All update/insert inside MyStoredProcedure will rollback.

Thanks

Comment: Depends what happens in `MYstoreProcedure` and if it has it's own explicit transactions.

Comment: Of course, this looks very simple for you to test your Development environment. Why didn't you?

Comment: First executed `commit` within any procedure will commit the whole transaction.

Comment: thank you now is clear.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Handling Transactions in Nested SQL Server Stored Procedures](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4897/handling-transactions-in-nested-sql-server-stored-procedures/).

Comment: @Serg that is incorrect, see @@trancount. You can test your assertion easily and prove it to be false.

Comment: @HABO you posted a link to a 404 error, however this question arises frequently and has been documented many times eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692734/sql-server-nested-transactions-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @sTTu Odd, I copied a fresh URL for the comment and the link works for me now. I can refresh the target page, so it isn't just something lurking in my cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided you have

```
set xact_Abort on
```

at the start of your transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch to execute rollback if any error occurs otherwise execute commit. Here goes a simple example.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A',3,'E');   
    
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(1);  
INSERT INTO ValueTable VALUES(2);  

exec MYstoreProcedure

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN   
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    throw;
    END 
END CATCH;
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN   
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'Successfully Completed'
    END
```

Comment: And what do you do if the transaction is uncomittable in the `catch`? this is why you should use `xact_abort`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Handling SQL Server Errors in Nested Procedures
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74479802/6204480